# Что означает запись "5e-6" в C#?

Tags: c#

В C# я не особо шарю, пишу в основном на python-3.
Хотел перевести данный код, но никак не могу понять откуда взялось 5e? (строка 15)

```
public void Bezier2D(double[] b, int cpts, double[] p)
{
    int npts = (b.Length) / 2;
    int icount, jcount;
    double step, t;

    // Вычисляем точки на кривой

    icount = 0;
    t = 0;
    step = (double)1.0 / (cpts - 1);

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 != cpts; i1++)
    { 
        if ((1.0 - t) < 5e-6) //  <<< --- Что такое 5e-6 ?
            t = 1.0;

        jcount = 0;
        p[icount] = 0.0;
        p[icount + 1] = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i != npts; i++)
        {
            double basis = Bernstein(npts - 1, i, t);
            p[icount] += basis * b[jcount];
            p[icount + 1] += basis * b[jcount + 1];
            jcount = jcount +2;
        }

        icount += 2;
        t += step;
    }
}
```

Ссылка на  [источник](http://www.cyberguru.ru/algorithms/algorithms-theory/curves-bezier.html)

Comment: `5e-6` - это экспоненциальная запись числа, эквивалентная `5*10^-6` или `0.000005`

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`5e-6` - это [экспоненциальная запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) числа, эквивалентная `5*10^-6` или `0.000005`