# Тип double его диапазон, что за Е?

Tags: математика, числа

Начнем с того, что я знаком с типом double, но не понимаю его диапазон:

```
double  от -4.9e-324 до 1.7e+308
```

И поэтому не могу понять ниже переменную которая в себя принимает вот такое значение: `6.67300E-11`, объясните пожалуйста, что за E и дефис с 11

```
// Гравитационная постоянная, мА3 / кг-эА2 
private static final double G = 6.67300E-11;
```

3.302e+23 это 3.302 * 10^23?

И чем отличается 3.302e+23 от 2.439e6

В википедии наткнулся на такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это называется [экспоненциальная запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). В школе, вроде бы, проходят.

Comment: в англоязычной литературе `Scientific notation`

Comment: Не могу понять про диапазон double

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что означает запись "5e-6" в C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/575478/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-5e-6-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: @Grundy да я уже даже там вам плюсик поставил), но у меня вопрос чутка глубже

Comment: @Grundy Просто в википедии смотрю и пытаюсь понять, правильно ли у меня получается записывать или нет

Comment: И в чем же именно ваш вопрос "глубже"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По поводу E в комментариях уже написали, что это *экспоненциальная запись*.

x E y означает x × 10<sup>y</sup>.

Теперь что касается диапазона `double`.

Числа с плавающей точкой двойной точности, те самые `double` занимают 64 бита. Из них 1 бит это *знак* (1 — отрицательное число, 0 — положительное), 11 бит *порядок* и 52 бита *мантисса*.

Порядок — это степень. Одиннадцать бит хватает для хранения степени от -1022 до +1023, плюс два *особых случая*. Более точно, в двоичных числах мы возводим в степень 2, а не 10, поэтому речь идёт о числах от 2<sup>-1022</sup> до 2<sup>1023</sup>.

Если перевести к показателю 10, у нас получится от ~10<sup>-308</sup> до ~10<sup>308</sup>

Мантисса это дробная часть числа в двоичной записи. Например, 100...000<sub>2</sub> (здесь 52 двоичных цифры) означают число 1,100...000<sub>2</sub>.

Верхняя граница 1,7×10<sup>308</sup> это на самом деле 1,111...111<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>1023</sup>.

Нормальные дробные числа в области, близкой к нулю равны 1,000...000<sub>2</sub>×2<sup>-1022</sup>, то есть где-то 2,2×10<sup>-308</sup>.

Вопрос, откуда взялся показатель -324. Это один их *особых случаев*, так называемые ненормализованные числа. Я бы не рекомендовал работать в этом диапазоне, поскольку точность здесь уже меньше, чем 52 двоичных знака.